# Using AJAX for Inserting UserName, Password in SqlServer

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I have very straight code to insert userName and password in sqlServer using JQuery-Ajax. I am checking the available resources over the web in this context but still facing this persistent issue to store the data in Db.

```html
User Name : <input type="text" id="t1" name="name" /><br />
Password : <input type="text" id="t2" name="name" /><br />
<button id="btn1">Insert Password</button>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn1').click(function () {
        var UserNm = $('#t1').val();
        var UserPwd = $('#t2').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'WebForm2.aspx/InsertPwdMethod',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { 
                UserName: UserNm, 
                Password: UserPwd 
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function() {
                alert('Job done..!');
            },
            error: function(returnValue) {
                alert(returnValue);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

```csharp
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void InsertPwdMethod(string UserName, string Password)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True");
    sqlConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into UserNamePassword values ('" + UserName + "','" + Password + "')",sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

How can I catch back a value from some other Method in C# if it returns a value? Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: You should NEVER store a plaintext password, ever.

Comment: Also, you are wide open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: I am getting back an Object in alertBox coming from Erro handling

Comment: @ChrisPickford, I agree but this is not production code at all.

Comment: @DotNET Never. Ever.

Comment: @ChrisPickford, Could you please share some thought how can one get return in this, as in question?

Answer (score 0):

Your data json doesn't seem to be formed correctly. Try this:

```
var jsonData = {};
jsonData['UserName'] = UserNm;
jsonData['Password'] = UserPwd;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'WebForm2.aspx/InsertPwdMethod',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() {
        alert('Job done..!');
    },
    error: function(returnValue) {
        alert(returnValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this working at your end? I am still getting same err.

Comment: Are you using chrome dev tools. Please could you view your console is this error coming from the javascript or the server.

Comment: I think this Err is coming form server : POST 
XHR 
http://localhost/Magento/WebForm2.aspx/InsertPwdMethod [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 4ms] , But I am able to store in database from WebForm2.aspx itself.

Comment: It is Firefox browser

Comment: Ok error 500 means it's a server error. Put a try catch around your web method and see what the error says? Or debug and find the server error....

Answer (score 0):

Describing the charset as utf-8 broke my *MVC* model binding.

Try changing this:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

to:

```
contentType: 'application/json',
```

Comment: Actually this is not a MVC application also, JSON data is good going. I am experiencing this error from Server side. Still putting break point on WebMethod is not executed..!! I am not sure why.